# Did the Joseon dynasty ask the Ming/Qing emperors for permission to crown a new king?

Tags: political-history, china, early-modern, asia, korea

Since they were vassals of [Ming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty) and [Qing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty) dynasties, did the [Joseon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseon) kings ask permission for their coronation?

Comment: Is this already answered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseon)? ""After much internal deliberation, as well as endorsement by the neighboring Ming dynasty's emperor, Taejo declared the name of the kingdom to be Joseon, a tribute to the ancient Korean state of Gojoseon."

Comment: @MCW That sounds like a different thing to me.

Comment: "endorsement by" implies that they asked permission.

Comment: @MCW "declar[ing] the name of the kingdom" does not sound like "coronation". E.g. it is possible to have many coronations of new rulers without declaring the name of the kingdom again.

Comment: @MCW the question is not entirely clear, but the usage of "kings" in plural makes me suspect that what is meant is "did Joseon court ask Ming/Qing courts for permission every time they wanted to crown a new king?"

Comment: Also I am not sure that "endorsement" implies "asking for permission". E.g. [some random news article](https://eu.jconline.com/story/news/politics/2022/12/15/west-lafayette-mayor-john-dennis-endorses-erin-easter-to-succeed-him/69722077007/) makes it seem that endorsement is nice-to-have, while permission is usually something necessary.